# How can a "referenced assembly" verify the signature/authenticity of the "caller assembly"?

Tags: .net, security, .net-assembly, digital-signature, authenticode

My question is with regard to enforcing security between .NET assemblies. And here's the scenario:

- A **Foundation** assembly is deployed on a server.
- A series of **Plugin** assemblies are shipped in an application.
- The **plugins** use functionality from the **Foundation**.
- Since the **Foundation** provides sensitive operations and data, it has to ensure that the **Plugin** (the caller assembly) is authentic and from a certain publisher.

I'm pretty new to security and have a basic grasp of Strong-Naming and Digital Signatures. So, if you can please give a thorough explanation of possible ways to accomplish the mentioned goal, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do the foundation and plugins reside on the same server?

Comment: `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Sorry, when reading your question again I understand that you don't control the plugins.

You want to restrict usage of the foundation assembly based on the assembly calling it.

Unfortunatly there is no other way to do that than checking the calling assembly in the sensitive parts. If you avoid public static members you can do the check in the constructor.

```
public class SensitiveClass {
    private readonly byte[] SupplierXKey = new[] {...};

    public SensitiveClass() {
        var key = Assembly.CallingAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKey();

        if (!key.SequenceEqual(SupplierXKey)) {
            throw new SecurityException();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this solution requires that your supplier protects their code as well. You might need to extend the above code to check the caller's caller and so on.

---

**old wrong answer**

Are you using MEF to load the plugins?

Then you can create your own catalog that only allows assemblies signed with a specific key.

Something like:

```
public class OnlyAssembliesFromX : ComposablePartCatalog
{
    private readonly byte[] SupplierXKey = new[] {...};

    AggregateCatalog _catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

    public OnlyAssemblisFromX(string path) {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {
            var key = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file)
                                  .GetPublicKey();

            if (key.SequenceEqual(SupplierXKey)) {
                _catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(file));
            }
        }
    }

    public override IQueryable<ComposablePartDefinition> Parts {
        get { return _aggregateCatalog.Parts; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @adrianm and thanks. Let me see if I understand this correctly: the SensitiveClass in your code is my Foundation, and the CallingAssembly would be the plugin, right? If I check the public key of the CallingAssembly with a value that's known to SensitiveClass, then I can be sure that plugin is authentic? 2 Questions: 1. Can a hacker create a plugin and give it the same name + version + public key? 2.this means that my SensitiveClass should somehow know (maybe download at runtime) the expected public key of the plugin from a trusted server through secure channel?

Comment: The hacker need your trusted supplier's private key to create an assembly with correct public key.

Comment: Regarding you second question. A public key is just that, public. You do not need an encrypted channel for the key but the channel must be protected against man-in-the middle attacks.

Comment: Thanks @adrianm :) Your comments have been very helpful. Greatly appreciated.